# View in Constraint Layout moves to top on changing width and height in Java

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

When I modify the width and height of button in java (Constraint Layout) then the button automatically moves to the top on click. Please check the code below and let me know what the issue is. PS - I am new to constraint layout

**Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibEgg"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/egg" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
ibEgg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(250,350);
                        ibEgg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(300,400);
                        ibEgg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new LayoutParams, So you will need to set constraint programatically, this is the way:

```
ibEgg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(250, 350);
                    layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    layoutParams.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    layoutParams.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    ibEgg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(300, 400);
                    layoutParams1.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    layoutParams1.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    layoutParams1.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    layoutParams1.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
                    ibEgg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```